# Should I include projects that are in development in my CV?

Tags: projects

I am making an application for loading, displaying and classifying 3d data.
The classifying part is in early development.
I am applying for an entry level job (internship) in IT.
Should I include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would serve no useful purpose to do so. All it shows is that you have an unfinished project somewhere (I got about 20 of them, many of which will probably NEVER be completed and I cannibalise for code once in a while).

However because it's yours, it could be useful during the interviews when they ask to see some code or such like.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "should I include *<X>* on my CV?" is always "only if *<X>* will improve the chances of getting an interview" - basically the entire purpose of a CV is to get you an interview. Does your in development project demonstrate skills (probably programming/software design skills in your case) above and beyond what people can see from the rest of your CV? If so, then definitely include it. If not, then it's not particularly interesting to anyone, so leave it off.